# Conditional statement for DropdownButtonFormFields in registeration form

Tags: flutter, forms, dropdown, form-fields, dropdownbutton

Still a newbie with flutter and was wondering if someone could help me with a problem I'm having. I am trying to create a registeration form with email, password, password confirmation, a county and a zip code. (County and zip code forms are the drop down button form fields) I have successfully coded all else except for the zip code drop down. I would need it to be conditional on the county selection. (In a way that if I select a specific county in cali, it would only display that selected county's zip codes and nothing else). Also if someone would know a quick fix to make the dropdown button form fields empty unless clicked on. My current adaptation on it isn't very functional, since you can just leave the option unanswered, when it's supposed to be mandatory. Thank you in advance :)

Existing code below

(I only have the string for one county zip codes) (Also deleted the irrelevant firebase related code for this post)

```
    class RegisterPage extends StatefulWidget {
      const RegisterPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      State<RegisterPage> createState() => _RegisterPageState();
    }

    class _RegisterPageState extends State<RegisterPage> {

      // dropdown area
      _MyFormStateArea(){
  selectedArea = dropdownListArea[0];
  }
  var selectedArea = '';
  final dropdownListArea = <String>['', 'LA', 'San Francisco'...'Santa Barbara'];

  // dropdown zipcode
  _MyFormStateZip(){
  selectedZip = dropdownListZip[0];
  }
  var selectedZip = '';
  final dropdownListZip = <String>['', '90001', '90002', '90003',..., '91609'];

  // editing Controller
  final emailEditingController = new TextEditingController();
  final passwordEditingController = new TextEditingController();
  final confirmPasswordEditingController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // email field
    final emailField = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      controller: emailEditingController,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          return ("Please enter email.");
        }
        // reg expression for email validation
        if (!RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-z]")
            .hasMatch(value)) {
          return ("Please enter a working email.");
        }
        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (value) {
        emailEditingController.text = value!;
      },
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail_outline_outlined),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
        hintText: "Email",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
        ),
      ),
    );

    // password field
    final passwordField = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      controller: passwordEditingController,
      obscureText: true,
      validator: (value) {
        RegExp regex = new RegExp(r'^.{6,}$');
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          return ("A password required.");
        }
        if(!regex.hasMatch(value)) {
          return ("Please enter other password (Min. 6 characters)");
         }
        },
      onSaved: (value) {
        passwordEditingController.text = value!;
      },
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_outlined),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
        hintText: "Password",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
      ));

    // confirm password field
    final confirmPasswordField = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      controller: confirmPasswordEditingController,
      obscureText: true,
      validator: (value)
      {
        if(confirmPasswordEditingController.text != passwordEditingController.text)
        {
          return "Passwords don't match";
        }
        return null;
      },
      onSaved: (value) {
        confirmPasswordEditingController.text = value!;
      },
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_outlined),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
        hintText: "Password again",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
        ),
      ),
    );

    // area dropdown
    final areaField = DropdownButtonFormField(
        value: selectedArea,
        items: dropdownListArea.map((e) =>
            DropdownMenuItem(value: e, child: Text(e),)).toList(),
        onChanged: (String? value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value != null) {
              selectedArea = value;
            }
          });
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'County',
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_city_outlined),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 0, 10),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        )
    );

    // zip code field
    final zipCodeField = DropdownButtonFormField(
        value: selectedZip,
        items: dropdownListZip.map((e) =>
            DropdownMenuItem(value: e, child: Text(e),)).toList(),
        onChanged: (String? value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value != null) {
              selectedZip = value;
            }
          });
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Zip Code',
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 0, 10),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        )
    );

    // sign up button
    final signUpButton = Material(
      elevation: 5,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      color: Colors.white,
      child: MaterialButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        onPressed: () {
          signUp(emailEditingController.text, passwordEditingController.text);
        },
        child: Text("Sign Up", textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,
                color: Colors.lightBlue[900],
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
        ),
      ),
    );


    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFAED8E6),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FrontPage()));
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              color: Colors.lightBlue[900],
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            color: Color(0xFFAED8E6),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(36, 20, 36, 30),
              child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child:
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[

                      SizedBox(
                          height: 170,
                          child: Image.asset("assets/AR_logoBold.png",
                              fit: BoxFit.contain
                          )),
                      SizedBox(height: 40,),
                      emailField,
                      SizedBox(height: 25,),
                      passwordField,
                      SizedBox(height: 25,),
                      confirmPasswordField,
                      SizedBox(height: 25,),
                      areaField,
                      SizedBox(height: 25,),
                      zipCodeField,
                      SizedBox(height: 35,),
                      signUpButton,
                      SizedBox(height: 15,),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("You already own an account? "),
                          GestureDetector(onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
                          },
                            child: Text("Login",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    color: Colors.lightBlue[900])
                            ),)
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should initalize the selectedArea and selectedZip with the first Entry of your List: = dropdownListZip.first and the first entry should not be an empty String

To get only zips that belong to the choosen area you need to know them. At the moment you have two independent lists.
Better you use a map like:

```
Map<String, List<String>> zipmap = Map('LA': ['9000','9001','9002], 'San Francisco': ['9003', '9004']);
```

Than you can only display zips that belong to the area quite easy.

Take a look at: [Flutter Documentation for Map](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Map-class.html)

```
Map<String, List<String>> zipmap = Map('LA': ['9000','9001','9002], 'San Francisco': ['9003', '9004']);   

final areaField = DropdownButtonFormField(
        value: selectedArea,
        items: zipmap.keys.toList().map((e) =>
            DropdownMenuItem(value: e, child: Text(e),)).toList(),
        onChanged: (String? value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value != null) {
              selectedArea = value;
            }
          });
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'County',
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_city_outlined),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 0, 10),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        )
    );

// zip code field
    final zipCodeField = DropdownButtonFormField(
        value: selectedZip,
        items: zipmap[selectedArea].map((e) =>
            DropdownMenuItem(value: e, child: Text(e),)).toList(),
        onChanged: (String? value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value != null) {
              selectedZip = value;
            }
          });
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Zip Code',
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 0, 10),
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        )
    );
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I just can't seem to get it working. I don't know or seem to find anywhere how to implement the two strings from the map into two seperate dropdown button form fields :/

Comment: Hi. Because the cities are the keys of the map you can do it like: zipmap.keys.toList() and to get the zips you can do: zipmap['LA']

Comment: @Rasse I provided your code changed to my suggestions. It's not tested but you should be able to understand what I tried to explain. Maybe you need to create two variables keeping these lists because you can't reference a variable in an initializer. Therefore you can write a function and put it in the init() methode at the beginning of your stateful widget.